# Replace html radio buttons with image using CSS (without jquery)

Tags: radio-button

I have a yes/no radio button for impute. I customized it with CSS and changed into buttons (yes/green - No/Red). By default both buttons are in grey color. When i click 'yes' button it is changing into Blue. I have done it with CSS. But while clicking the 'No' button, it is not changing into red color. I'm not sure how to implement it. Below is the fiddle link.

HTML:

```
<span id="radioButton">
   <input name="radio_13" id="radio_13Yes" value="Yes" type="radio">
   <label class="Yes Ui2Clickable" id="label_radio_13Yes">Yes</label>
   <input name="radio_13" id="radio_13No" value="No" type="radio">
   <label class="No Ui2Clickable" id="label_radio_13No">No</label>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio] {
    margin:10px;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
    filter     : none;
    background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #cccccc);
    background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), color-stop(50%, #f9f9f9), to(#ccc));
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff;
    font-family: 'Meiryo';
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 80px;
    line-width: 160px;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Meiryo';
    font-weight: 700;
    max-width: 400px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label{
    filter     : none;
    background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #13213b, #0088ce);
    background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#13213b), color-stop(0.5,#3366cc), to(#0088ce));
    border: 2px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
    font-family: 'Meiryo';
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

CSS for Red(No) color button

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label .No{
    filter     : none;
    background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc0000, #FF1821);
    background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cc0000), color-stop(0.5,#FF1821), to(#FF1821));
    border: 2px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
    font-family: 'Meiryo';
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myve53r5/ (fiddle updated)

(I don;t want to use jQuery)

Comment: It's working on Chrome on my pc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myve53r5/
Please try on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your CSS

```
input[type=radio] {
margin:10px;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
filter     : none;
background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #cccccc);
background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), color-stop(50%, #f9f9f9), to(#ccc));
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff;
font-family: 'Meiryo';
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: 700;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 80px;
line-width: 160px;
padding: 15px 40px;
border: 1px solid #333;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: 'Meiryo';
font-weight: 700;
max-width: 400px;
}

#radio_13Yes:checked + label{
filter     : none;
background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #13213b, #0088ce);
background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#13213b), color-stop(0.5,#3366cc), to(#0088ce));
border: 2px solid #333;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
font-family: 'Meiryo';
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: 700;
}
#radio_13No:checked + label{
filter     : none;
background : linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc0000, #FF1821);
background : -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cc0000), color-stop(0.5,#FF1821), to(#FF1821));
border: 2px solid #333;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
font-family: 'Meiryo';
font-size: 16pt;
font-weight: 700;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0w5zLsp1/

Comment: Please explain the differences between your answer and the question CSS

Comment: Thanks Mohan, The Entire Html part is in a loop. The 'id' is built dymically like radio_13Yes, radio_14Yes. So I cannot specify the id in CSS. Is there any other way we can do it?

Comment: Ya. We can do this using class.Please check the link. http://jsfiddle.net/0w5zLsp1/2/